# Generating combined jacoco coverage report for integration tests

Tags: java, code-coverage, jacoco, jacoco-maven-plugin

I have a situation where my integration tests run like these

1. Start java process 1
2. Start java process 2
3. Fire integration tests which interact with the two processes started before

I started the two processes with `-javaagent:<path to jacocoagent.jar>=destfile=<path to exec file>,append=true`

I now have a exec file generated by jacoco which i think has combined coverage from both process one and two. I want to generate the report from this exec file. I read this link https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jacoco/odVzr7P5i6w which talks about how to do this but i have not been successful. The report generated using `report-aggregate` generated an empty report for me.

Please help me. Any help/pointer is greatly appreciated.

P.S. My apologies if i have missed anything obvious.